# Retrieving the last message of each conversation where a user is a participent

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `messages`:

```
| id | from_id | to_id | text 
+----+---------+-------+------------------
| 1  | 1       | 2     | from 1 to 2
| 2  | 2       | 1     | from 2 to 1
| 3  | 1       | 3     | from 1 to 3
| 4  | 3       | 1     | from 3 to 1
| 5  | 2       | 3     | from 2 to 3
| 6  | 1       | 2     | from 1 to 2 (2)
```

What would be the simplest query that would retrieve the last message of each conversation where a user is a participant (either a sender - `from_id` or a recipient - `to_id`)?

The result should be:

```
| id | from_id | to_id | text 
+----+---------+-------+------------------
| 4  | 3       | 1     | from 3 to 1
| 6  | 1       | 2     | from 1 to 2 (2)
```

---

Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `messages`
WHERE `id` IN (
    SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `messages`
    WHERE `from_id` = 1 OR `to_id` = 1
    GROUP BY `from_id`, `to_id`
)
```

The problem with it is that, in conversations where the user has been both a sender and a recipient, it retrieves both the last message that the user sent and the last message that the user received.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev Thanks for your edit, it is much better.Please don't feel that I'm picking on you. I'm just trying to get you to ask a question that makes it easier for other users to help, it also gives users coming to the site a better idea if your question will help solve their problem.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. The data you say you should be getting ("the results should be") looks like the data you say you don't want to be getting (" the last question that the user sent and the last question it received").

Comment: @EmanuilRusev Latest being based off what column - the `id`? or do you have a date time?

Comment: @bluefeet Yes, it can be the latest based on `id`.

Comment: @MattEllen The problem is that these are results that belong to the same conversation. Only one message per conversation should be retrieved and it should be the last one (the one that has the highest `id`).

Comment: @MattEllen I updated the question to make this a bit more clear.

Comment: Oh! I see, sorry, I get it now. the people in the conversations are not the same.

Comment: I had the same case previously with one difference. I had a `conversations` table and each message was linked to a conversation. You could have that even with a single conversation for any two people. I think the query is then easier. This is not a direct answer to the question and hence it's just a comment.

Comment: @HaralanDobrev Thanks, I'll consider it. Yet, I'd love see an answer.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

```
SELECT *
from messages
where id in 
(
  SELECT max(id)
    FROM messages
GROUP BY CASE WHEN from_id > to_id THEN concat(from_id, 'chat', to_id)
              ELSE concat(to_id, 'chat', from_id)
         END
) 
and (from_id = 1
  or to_id = 1)
```

I used the sub-query to get the last line of each chat:

```
  SELECT max(id)
    FROM messages
GROUP BY CASE WHEN from_id > to_id THEN concat(from_id, 'chat', to_id)
              ELSE concat(to_id, 'chat', from_id)
         END
```

You can check my updated demo in [SQLFiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/920dc/14)

Comment: I was just about to submit something like that.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in the cases where the user is the recipient of the last message of multiple conversations: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/920dc/1

Comment: I'm selecting a single row (the last one) for each conversation, then it's easy to pick-up only the rows with 1 in the from or to column